# How long does 'Git push -u' remember the parameters for?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I just got started with a tutorial on Git.

There, they mentioned a command

> git push -u origin master

where the changes made on local branch `master` are pushed to `origin` repository(on Github).
And the `-u` tells git to remember the parameters so that next time we can just write `git push`

Can someone tell me whether git remembers the parameters only for the very next time we use `git push`, or every time henceforth till a command to tell git to forget the parameters is written? Also, is any there such command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the command

```
git push -u origin master
```

The `-u` flag means that your local branch will become a tracking branch. That is, a branch that tracks a remote branch, so that future `git pull` will know which branch to merge from and `git push` will be directed to the correct remote branch.

Technically, the tracking adds the following information about the master branch to your `.git/config` file:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

and it creates a file here `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, representing the remote branch.

These settings are local to the current repository, so they will not apply to other repositories.

The changes in `.git/config` are permanent (until you explicitly change them), so the effects of `git push -u` are permanent.

Comment: Nicely detailed and well explained answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`git push -u` tells git to track the remote branch locally (an 'upstream tracking reference'), so `git push` whilst on the local branch will then always push to the remote branch specified in the initial `git push -u`. This will persist on the branch (or master in your case) until the next `push -u` you do (which will cause it to track another remote branch).

It's also used so that other git commands know where to retrieve data from e.g. `git pull` uses it to pull changes made to the remote being tracked to the local repo.